# Edge Detection, Matlab Vision System Toolbox

Tags: computer-vision, matlab-cvst, edge-detection

I have several images where I need to find an edge. I have tried following the vision.EdgeDetector System object in matlab, and the example they give here:  http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.edgedetectorclass.html

They give the example

```
    hedge = vision.EdgeDetector;
    hcsc = vision.ColorSpaceConverter('Conversion','RBG to intensity')
    hidtypeconv = vision.ImageDataTypeConverter('OutputDataType',single');
    img = step(hcsc, imread('picture.png'))
    img1 = step(hidtypeconv, ing);
    edge = step(hedge,img1);
    imshow(edges);
```

Which I have followed exactly in my code.

However this code doesn't produce all the edges I would like, it seems as though Matlab can only pick up on about half of the edges in the entire image. Is there a different approach I can take to finding all the edges, or a way to improve upon the vision.EdgeDetector object in Matlab?

Answer (score 2):

By default hedge = vision.EdgeDetector has a Threshold value of 20. Try changing it to hedge = vision.EdgeDetector('Threshold',***Value***) and play with ***value*** to see what value works out the best for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
imgGray = rgb2gray(imgRGB);
imgEdge = edge(imgGray,'canny');
```

This should give you most of the edge points, if not, then change parameters THRESH and SIGMA accordingly. Also check the following for other methods:

```
help edge
```

You do not have to use vision.EdgeDetector system, somethings are easier without them! ;)